# JasperReports can't export data with JSF 2 and PrimeFaces 3.5

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces, jasper-reports

I am developing an application with *PrimeFaces 3.5*, *JasperReports 5.2*, and *JSF 2.x*. I have some report pages in my old application prepared by *JasperReports 4.5* and *JSF 1.2*. All those report pages are working in the old application. I tried to transfer those report pages in my new application. Everything works fine in the new app but report cannot be exported and I don't get any error. Am I missing something?

Here is my code that works perfectly in my old *Jsf 1.2* app but not with the new app.

```
private void prepareReport(String reportPath, @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") List beanList, String outputFormat, String reportName) {
    JasperReport jReport = null;
    JasperPrint jPrint = null;
    try {
        jReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportPath);
        jPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jReport, jasperParameter, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(beanList));
    } catch (JRException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) ctx.getExternalContext().getResponse();
    OutputStream outputStream = null;

    try {
        outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        if (outputFormat.equals(OUTPUT_FORMAT_PDF)) {
            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + reportName + ".pdf");
            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jPrint, outputStream);
        } else if (outputFormat.equals(OUTPUT_FORMAT_EXCEL)) {
            response.setContentType("application/xls");
            response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + reportName + ".xls");
            JExcelApiExporter exporter = new JExcelApiExporter();
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jPrint);
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, outputStream);
            exporter.exportReport();
        } else if (outputFormat.equals(OUTPUT_FORMAT_RTF)) {
            response.setContentType("application/rtf");
            response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + reportName + ".rtf");
            JRRtfExporter exporter = new JRRtfExporter();
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jPrint);
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, outputStream);
            exporter.exportReport();
        }
    } catch (JRException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here is part of the JSF 2 xhtml page that I call the backing bean:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="4" columnClasses="alignTop,alignTop,alignTop,alignTop">
    <p:commandButton id="pdfFormatBtn" actionListener="#{reports.pdfFormatSelected}" value="PDF" immediate="true"
        icon="pdfIcon" styleClass="tableCell"/>
    <p:commandButton id="excelFormatBtn" actionListener="#{reports.pdfFormatSelected}" value="EXCEL" immediate="true"
        icon="excelIcon" styleClass="tableCell"/>
    <p:commandButton id="rtfFormatBtn" actionListener="#{reports.pdfFormatSelected}" value="RTF" immediate="true"
        icon="rtfIcon" styleClass="tableCell"/>
    <p:commandButton id="cleanBtn" actionListener="#" value="#{general.clean}" immediate="true"
        icon="ui-icon-refresh" styleClass="tableCell"/>
</h:panelGrid>
```

Comment: When you already using Primefaces why don't you consider using `<p:dataExporter>`http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/exporterHome.jsf?

Comment: I don't simply export some datatables, that is, what <p:dataExporter> does. I have really unique report pages designed by iReport designer of the JasperReport and I want to transfer all of them to the new app.

Comment: Do you have any idea why the above code works with JSF 1.2 and JasperReport 4.5 and does not work with JSF 2.x, JasperReport 5.2, and PrimeFaces 3.5? Really need help.

Answer (score 1):

Try using ajax="false"

`<p:commandButton id="pdfFormatBtn" actionListener="#{reports.pdfFormatSelected}" value="PDF" immediate="true" icon="pdfIcon" styleClass="tableCell" ajax="false"/>`